# rewrite URL - htaccess and apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Ive the following url ,

> http://system.test.com/login
>
> and

http://system.test.com/system/customer/portal/1

> when ever user  access 1st url  the content of 2nd url will be present

Which rewrite rule should help me with this /

Comment: Do you already have a .htaccess in your `DocumentRoot`? If yes place that code in question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the rewrite guide http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

I'll give you the answer :

`RewriteRule ^/login(.*)$ /system/customer/portal/1$1 [R]`

The first is a regular expression for what is after system.test.com/ and the second is the replacement. Here we replace /login with /system/customer/portal/1